# Help with global continuity...

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that $f(x)=x²$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ I know that I can prove it using deltas and epsilon (($ \delta(\delta + 2 \mid x_{0}\mid))<\epsilon)$ but how can I prove it using this:
 $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$   $f: A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ $f$ is continuous in $A$
if and only if $\forall W\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ open set (in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$), $\exists U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ open set (in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) that:
$f^{-1}(W)=U\cap A$ (relatively open)

Comment: You can restrict you to the open balls, as the open set in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) are generated from the open balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W$ be an open subset of $[0,\infty)$. We want to show $f^{-1}(W)$ is open in $\Bbb R$. Take $x\in f^{-1}(W)$. Then $x^2\in W$, so since $W$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that for all $y \ge 0$, $|y - x^2| < r$ implies $y \in W$. If $\delta = \min\{1, r/(1 + 2|x|)\}$, then for all $z\in \Bbb R$, $|z - x| < \delta$ implies

$$|z^2 - x^2| = |z + x||z - x| \le (|z - x| + 2|x|) |z - x| < (1 + 2|x|)\delta \le r,$$

which implies $z^2\in W$, or $z\in f^{-1}(W)$. Consequently, $x$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}(W)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $f^{-1}(W)$ is open.